# Time conversion returning null

Tags: php, time

My script:

```
$start = strtotime($color_date);
$end = strtotime($accessory_date);
$days_between = ceil(abs($end - $start) / 86400);
```

The `$days_between` result should be an integer, but it's returning `null`.

```
EDIT:

$color_date="24/04/2013";
$accessory_date="26/04/2013";
```

Comment: can you give input date?

Comment: Do a `var_dump` of your variables and see if they are what you think they are.

Comment: will you please add your input date format for both color_date and accessory_date ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok i got my script done

```
               $datetime1 = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $color_date);
               $color_date= $datetime1->format('Y-m-d');
               $datetime2 = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $accessory_date);
               $accessory_date= $datetime2->format('Y-m-d');
               $start = strtotime($color_date);
               $end = strtotime($accessory_date);
               $days_between = ceil(abs($end - $start) / 86400);
```

just converted my dates from d/m/Y to Y-m-d and hence problem solved

Answer (score 2):

I think you should not "invent your own wheel" when there's one already

You might want to have a look at [DateTime::diff](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php) for calculation of differences between two days.
Short example from that page:

```
<?php
$datetime1 = new DateTime('2009-10-11');
$datetime2 = new DateTime('2009-10-13');
$interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
echo $interval->format('%R%a days');
?>
```